# Neither cast nor convert is working for me using a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, casting

Below is my cast attempt:

```
cast((select count(distinct tm.MEMBER_ID) from #tempmemid as tm) as int(64))
```

After that didn't work I attempted to convert:

```
convert(int, (select count(distinct tm.MEMBER_ID) from #tempmemid as tm)
```

Is the syntax incorrect? Can someone explain the difference between cast and convert more finitely than the Google results I obtained?

The error messages I'm receiving for each are as follows:

cast: incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

&

convert: incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to cast or convert in the first place? count returns an int, so why cast/convert? If you want bigint, then @GordonLinoff's answer below makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first will work if you remove '(64)':

```
SELECT cast((select count(distinct tm.MEMBER_ID) from #tempmemid as tm) as int)
```

but as Sean points out below, there is no need to CAST a COUNT as INT.

The second has incorrect brackets:

```
SELECT convert(int, (select count(distinct tm.MEMBER_ID) from #tempmemid as tm))
```

Comment: This makes no sense. COUNT returns an int so this is casting an int as an int.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to `cast()` the return value of `count()` to an integer.  That is what the value already is.

I assume you want a `bigint`.  Don't use a `cast()`, use `count_big()`:

```
(select count_big(distinct tm.MEMBER_ID) from #tempmemid as tm)
```

This returns a `bigint`.